# Switching between gps and network provider

Tags: android, networking, gps, switching

In my app I set both providers with fine and coarse accuracy to listen for location updates. I understand that using fine the location will be provided by the gps, and using coarse the location will be provided by the network provider (from this link http://www.alonsoruibal.com/using-two-locationproviders-on-android/). Now if the gps is disabled I want my app to switch to network, and when gps is enabled to switch back to it. This can be done using `onStatusChanged` method right?
My question is, is this code ok?

```
public static final int OUT_OF_SERVICE = 0;
public static final int TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE = 1;
public static final int AVAILABLE = 2;

Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
criteria.setCostAllowed(false);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
providerFine = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
providerCoarse = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    if (provider.equals(providerFine)) {
        if (status == 0) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(providerCoarse, 60000,20,this);
        }
        if (status == 2) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(providerFine, 60000, 20, this);
        }
    }// provider == fine
}
```

And also, if updates are already requested, (somewhere before in my code, I didn't put that here) (for both providers), would it be ok if I request them again in this onStatusChanged method. Or I have to remove updates first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks fine to me. I would recommend removing any update listeners before adding anymore. To keep it clean and consistent.

Comment: Ok, thank u, I was wondering about that. Thanks

Comment: @Sandra can you please confirm the switching is working fine, i am trying to achieve a similar task.