# LocationManager GetBestProvider Criteria

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I want my LocationManager to attempt to get Fine_Location first, and then if not available get Coarse_Location.  Can this type of hierarchy be set up for the Criteria Accuracy property?

```
const string context = LocationService;
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(context);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria() { Accuracy = Accuracy.Fine | Accuracy.Coarse };
string provider = locationManager.GetBestProvider(criteria, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the documentation for the [`GetBestProvider()`](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=M%3aAndroid.Locations.LocationManager.GetBestProvider) method:

> Returns the name of the provider that best meets the given criteria.
>   Only providers that are permitted to be accessed by the calling
>   activity will be returned. **If several providers meet the criteria, the
>   one with the best accuracy is returned.**

This sounds like the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: I apologize if I was unclear.  When I have the Accuracy set to Fine but am indoors where I have network coverage but no GPS coverage, the location returns null.  But then when I set it to Course, it returns a value based on network coverage.  I want the location to be as accurate as possible, but I don't want it to return null if it can't get a GPS signal.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the location to be as accurate as possible, but I don't want it to return null if it can't get a GPS signal

Then you have to register for both providers - `provider = LocationManager.GetBestProvider(criteria, true);` will return the best *available* provider - it won't check to see if this provider can actually get a fix. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505429/switching-between-network-and-gps-provider/14237739#14237739) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019474/switching-between-gps-and-network-provider) for registering with both providers