# Gps status listener stops functioning once you call de-register a location listener

Tags: android, gps, android-location

`onGpsStatusChanged` of `GpsStatus.Listener` stops getting called once you call `removeUpdates` on a `LocationManager` instance. I originally had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497340/ongpsstatuschanged-not-firing-for-gpsstatus-listener) problem which I fixed. I'm trying to switch between gps based location tracking and network based location tracking. I've already looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505429/switching-between-network-and-gps-provider) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019474/switching-between-gps-and-network-provider). Most of the places they talk about requesting location updates from both providers simultaneously. I'm afraid this method would drain **battery** bigtime.

Hence I did something as follows. I had two `LocationListener`s: `gpsListener` and `ntListener`:

```
Listener mGPSListener = new GpsStatus.Listener() {

    @Override
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(final int event) {

        switch (event) {
            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
                locMgr.removeUpdates(ntListener);
                locMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 120000, 50, gpsListener);
                break;

            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
                locMgr.removeUpdates(gpsListener);
                locMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 120000, 50, ntListener);
                break;
        }


    }


};
```

Now once, `locMgr.removeUpdates` is hit, `onGpsStatusChanged` stops getting called. I tried several things such as adding `addGpsStatusListener`  after calling `removeUpdates` trying different gps status listeners, etc. No success yet. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add below line before calling requestLocationUpdates on both places :

```
locMgr.addGpsStatusListener(ntListener);

locMgr.addGpsStatusListener(gpsListener);
```